# Avoid pyramid of doom using angular $q and Stripe

Tags: angularjs, promise, stripe-payments, chaining

I'm attempting to do some promise chains using angular's implementation of `$q`, but seem to have hit a roadblock with almost being forced in to a pyramid-of-doom situation.

What I would prefer to do:

```
function doYetAnotherAsync() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        var transaction = {
            cvc: vm.cvc,
            exp_year: vm.expirationYear,
            exp_month: vm.expirationMonth,
            number: vm.cardNumber
        }
        Stripe.card.createToken(transaction, function(responseCode, response) {
            console.log('createToken');
            if(responseCode === 200) {
                resolve({
                    id: core.get(response, 'id'),
                    cardId: core.get(response, 'card.id')
                });
            }
            reject(response);
        });
    });
}

function doAnotherAsync() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        var globalVar;
        doSomeNormalAjaxCall()
        .then(function(response){
            globalVar = response.id;
            return doYetAnotherAsync()
        })
        .then(function(stripeData){
            console.log('stripeData', stripeData);
            // stripeData returns a $$state object
            return finalAsync()
        })
        .then(function(response){
            // handle final data here
            // resolve/reject $q
        })
    })
}

doSomeAsync()
.then(doAnotherAsync)
```

Notice in `doAnotherAsync()`, I would love to be able to use this form:

```
someAsync()
.then(function(){
    return someOtherAsync()
})
.then(function(){
    return yetAnotherAsync()
})
.then(function(){
    // finally do some stuff
})
```

To avoid the pyramid-of-doom.

However, in the above code, the second `.then()` resolves early and a `$$state` object is passed along the chain as opposed to a normal object of `{id: '', cardId: ''}`.

Example of `console.log` order:

```
stripeData d {$$state: Object}
XHR finished loading: POST "https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens"
createToken
```

To preserve the promise chaining order and get a real object response, I was forced to do:

```
function doAnotherAsync() {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject){
        var globalVar;
        doSomeNormalAjaxCall
        .then(function(response){
            globalVar = response.id;
            return doYetAnotherAsync()
            .then(function(stripeData){
                // some logic
                return finalyAsync()
            })
        })
        .then(function(response){
            // final processing
        })
    })
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It can definitely be solved. What is the role of `globalVar`? And what exactly is `doSomeNormalAjaxCall`, is it jQuery? There's something wrong with a promise that is returned from it. A promise can't pass unsettled promise down the chain ('resolve early'), $q and native promises are compliant and wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about making a pyramid.

Pyramids are not always avoidable and can allow :

- access to previous results through closure
- catching specific errors

By exploiting closure in a pyramid, you will typically avoid the need for an outer var (your `globalVar`), so it's surprising to see, in the working version, both a pyramid and an outer var.

It's hard to advise further as the code has been simplified to a point where the specific issue is not overt. The need for `globalVar` is not clear, and the pyramid looks like it should successfully flatten. Maybe something is going on in the `some logic` block or maybe there's a missing `return` in `finalyAsync()`.

Comment: Ah yeah, I pseudo coded all that, so I left the global in the second version, definitely no need for it, thanks for the tip. I think maybe it has to do with the Stripe call, but even with a `setTimeout(){ resolve() }` it was failing. This is part of a huge promise tree so it's not far from bad. Even with a slight pyramid. I'll try to toss a working version on JSBIN to see why. I can't figure out why it's doing what its doing, though. Thanks!

Comment: OK, i'll await a JSBIN link.